# Saxparser exception in Android

Tags: java, android

I am parsing data from this [XML url](http://maps.travelsouthyorkshire.com/iGNMSearchService.asmx/TextSearch?text=West%20bar&maxResults=100) The text input varies, depending on the user. Whenever there are spaces in the text variable I get this exception:

```
 org.apache.harmony.xml.ExpatParser$ParseException: At line 11, column 2: mismatched tag
 org.apache.harmony.xml.ExpatParser.parseFragment(ExpatParser.java:520)
 org.apache.harmony.xml.ExpatParser.parseDocument(ExpatParser.java:479)
 org.apache.harmony.xml.ExpatReader.parse(ExpatReader.java:318)
 org.apache.harmony.xml.ExpatReader.parse(ExpatReader.java:275)
 gps.app.tkartor.XMLObjects.XMLParser.findStreet(XMLParser.java:99)
```

If there are no spaces it works fine. Parsing code:

```
public void findStreet(String searchWord) {
    try {
        url = new URL(
                "http://maps.travelsouthyorkshire.com/iGNMSearchService.asmx/TextSearch?text="
                        + searchWord + "&maxResults=100");
        System.out.println(url.toString());
        parserFactory = SAXParserFactory.newInstance();
        parser = parserFactory.newSAXParser();
        reader = parser.getXMLReader();
        streetHandler = new StreetHandler();
        reader.setContentHandler(streetHandler);
        reader.parse(new InputSource(url.openStream()));//line 99
        poi = streetHandler.getAllStreets();

    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Indicate spaces with '+'

http://maps.travelsouthyorkshire.com/iGNMSearchService.asmx/TextSearch?text=West+bar&maxResults=100

So in your case you have to replace the spaces of your String "searchWord". Something like

```
 searchWord = searchWord.replace(" ", "+");
```

Answer (score 1):

When I view both of those URLs using my web browser, I get valid XML.  Certainly, there is no error at line 11 as indicated by your stacktrace.

My conclusion is that fetching the URLs (particularly the one with the space in it) is giving a different result when you do it programmatically versus doing it in a web browser.  I expect that is because the browser is "helpfully" fixing the URL to encode the space character before sending it.  (And I suspect that you pasted that fixed URL into the question ...)

To confirm this diagnosis, you need to capture and view the actual file contents that your Android app gets from the server.  My guess is that it is actually an HTML error page.  That typically won't be valid XML, and hence the XML parse error.

If this turns out to be the problem, then you need to correctly encode the search string before embedding it in the URL.  If you were using plain Java, then I'd suggest using `URLEncoder.encode`, or assembling the URL from its components using the `URI` class.  There may be a better way on the Android platform ...