# Android mismatched tag Exception all of sudden

Tags: android

Earlier while Parsing the data I never get such `Exception` but today all of a sudden I get the `TAG mismatch Exception`. I don't know where I m getting wrong. Please help me out.

Url parsing:`http://development.21stcenturymart.com/TopCategory.php`

**Error Trace:**

```
03-18 12:52:08.070: W/System.err(10156): org.apache.harmony.xml.ExpatParser$ParseException: At line 35, column 2: mismatched tag
03-18 12:52:08.070: W/System.err(10156):    at org.apache.harmony.xml.ExpatParser.parseFragment(ExpatParser.java:515)
03-18 12:52:08.070: W/System.err(10156):    at org.apache.harmony.xml.ExpatParser.parseDocument(ExpatParser.java:474)
03-18 12:52:08.070: W/System.err(10156):    at org.apache.harmony.xml.ExpatReader.parse(ExpatReader.java:321)
03-18 12:52:08.070: W/System.err(10156):    at org.apache.harmony.xml.ExpatReader.parse(ExpatReader.java:279)
03-18 12:52:08.070: W/System.err(10156):    at com.centuery.ctl21.Centuary_MainActivity$Toplist.doInBackground(Centuary_MainActivity.java:697)
03-18 12:52:08.070: W/System.err(10156):    at com.centuery.ctl21.Centuary_MainActivity$Toplist.doInBackground(Centuary_MainActivity.java:1)
03-18 12:52:08.070: W/System.err(10156):    at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:287)
03-18 12:52:08.070: W/System.err(10156):    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:305)
03-18 12:52:08.070: W/System.err(10156):    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:137)
03-18 12:52:08.070: W/System.err(10156):    at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:230)
03-18 12:52:08.070: W/System.err(10156):    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1076)
03-18 12:52:08.070: W/System.err(10156):    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:569)
03-18 12:52:08.070: W/System.err(10156):    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:856)
```

Source code

```
SAXParserFactory spf=SAXParserFactory.newInstance();      
        SAXParser sp= spf.newSAXParser();
        XMLReader xr=sp.getXMLReader();

        URL soUrl=new URL(CommonUtilities.url_TopCategoy);


        CategoryHandler dh = new CategoryHandler();
        xr.setContentHandler(dh);
        xr.parse(new InputSource (soUrl.openStream()));
        Log.v("urllllllllllllllll",""+soUrl);
```

Comment: see this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9857288/saxparser-exception-in-android. also see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10875899/error-when-parsing-a-url-using-android-code

Comment: I have referred but all in vain user3355820

Comment: try http://androidbite.blogspot.in/2012/11/android-sax-parser-example.html

Answer (score 1):

Finally after Battling for So long got the Solution.
 My problem is with my Wifi connection. It was not connected to Authenticated Wifi Connection. So to Check if the Wifi is Enable or Disable Run the Following Code:
 You can register a BroadcastReceiver to be notified when a WiFi connection is established (or if the connection changed).
Register the BroadcastReceiver:

```
IntentFilter intentFilter = new IntentFilter();
intentFilter.addAction(WifiManager.SUPPLICANT_CONNECTION_CHANGE_ACTION);
registerReceiver(broadcastReceiver, intentFilter);

And then in your BroadcastReceiver do something like this:

@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    final String action = intent.getAction();
    if (action.equals(WifiManager.SUPPLICANT_CONNECTION_CHANGE_ACTION)) {
        if (intent.getBooleanExtra(WifiManager.EXTRA_SUPPLICANT_CONNECTED, false)){
            //do stuff
        } else {
            // wifi connection was lost
        }
    }
}
```

For more info, see the documentation for BroadcastReceiver and WifiManager

Of course you should check whether the device is already connected to WiFi before this.